# How to call only php function not whole page with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I want to return data only from the php function not whole page data.
Here is my demo.php file -

```
    <?
    echo "Whole Page data";

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if ($name == "demo"){
        demo();
    }
    else{
        echo "No";
    }
    function demo(){
       echo "demo data";
}

?>
```

And my ajax funtion is this -

```
function myAjax () {
        $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
                url  : 'demo.php',
                data : "name=demo",
                success:function(data){
                       alert (data);
               }
       });
}
```

But it return whole page data with function data but I want only function data.

Comment: Remove the line `echo "Whole Page data";`

Comment: hey @Himanshu Upadhyay its a sample code , line echo "Whole Page data" is sample. Actually there is another code So I need that code.

Comment: But @HimanshuUpadhyay did it right. Because I started laughing immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check like,

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if ($name == "demo") {
        demo();
    } else {
        echo "No";
    }
    die;
}
function demo()
{
    echo "demo data";
}
```

This `die;` is important to halt execution process.

Give it a try, this should work.